# C++ Remove the last new line

Tags: c++, graph, shortest-path

I'm using `cout` and `endl`to print some guides, the output (my intention) is like:

```
From Spot 1
Spot 2
Spot 5
Spot 8
Spot 6
To Spot 3
```

Here, the Spot `No.` is random and generated from some iterations. Because of iterations, i can only print the result like:

```
From Spot 1
Spot 2
Spot 5
Spot 8
Spot 6
Spot 3
```

Is there any method to remove my last new line `Spot 3`?

### **EDIT:**

I want to find the shortest path (using Floyd-Warshall Algorithm) between two vertices. Here's my code, and it describes the following gragh:
[image]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int INF = 100000;
int n = 10, path[11][11], dist[11][11], map[11][11];
void init() {
    int i, j;
    for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
        for ( j = 1; j <= n; j++ )
            map[i][j] = ( i == j ) ? 0:INF;
    map[1][2] = 2, map[1][4] = 20, map[2][5] = 1;
    map[3][2] = 3, map[4][3] = 8, map[4][6] = 6;
    map[4][7] = 4, map[5][3] = 7, map[5][8] = 3;
    map[6][3] = 1, map[7][8] = 1, map[8][6] = 2;
    map[8][10] = 2, map[9][7] = 2, map[10][9] = 1;
}
void floyd() {
    int i, j, k;
    for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
        for ( j = 1; j <= n; j++ )
            dist[i][j] = map[i][j], path[i][j] = 0;
    for ( k = 1; k <= n; k++ )
        for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
            for ( j = 1; j <= n; j++ )
                if ( dist[i][k] + dist[k][j] < dist[i][j] )
                    dist[i][j] = dist[i][k] + dist[k][j], path[i][j] = k;
}
void output( int i, int j ) {
    if ( i == j ) return;
    if ( path[i][j] == 0 ) cout << "Spot" << j << endl;
    else {
        output( i, path[i][j] );            // iterations
        output( path[i][j], j );
    }
}
int main() {
    int u, v;
    init();
    floyd();
    u = 1, v = 3;
    if ( dist[u][v] == INF ) cout << "No path" << endl;
    else {
        cout << "From Spot" << u << endl;
        output( u, v );
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem now is to find the conditon of the last iteration so that i can `cout` a different expression. But i think it is more easier to solve the problem by simply removing the last expression and rewriting, so i didnt attach my code.

### **EDIT 2:**

I've achieved my purpose with the help of Fabian Tamp though it seems a little stupid of me writing the code above. Here goes the modified code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

const int INF = 100000;
int n = 10, path[11][11], dist[11][11], map[11][11];
void init() {
    int i, j;
    for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
        for ( j = 1; j <= n; j++ )
            map[i][j] = ( i == j ) ? 0:INF;
    map[1][2] = 2, map[1][4] = 20, map[2][5] = 1;
    map[3][3] = 3, map[4][3] = 8, map[4][6] = 6;
    map[4][7] = 4, map[5][3] = 7, map[5][8] = 3;
    map[6][3] = 1, map[7][8] = 1, map[8][6] = 2;
    map[8][10] = 2, map[9][7] = 2, map[10][9] = 1;
}

void floyd() {
    int i, j, k;
    for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
        for ( j = 1; j <= n; j++ )
            dist[i][j] = map[i][j], path[i][j] = 0;
    for ( k = 1; k <= n; k++ )
        for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
            for ( j = 1; j <= n; j++ )
                if ( dist[i][k] + dist[k][j] < dist[i][j] )
                    dist[i][j] = dist[i][k] + dist[k][j], path[i][j] = k;
}

void output( int i, int j, queue<int> &output_queue ) {
    if ( i == j ) return;
    if ( path[i][j] == 0 ) output_queue.push(j);
    else {
        output( i, path[i][j], output_queue);            // iterations
        output( path[i][j], j, output_queue);
    }
}

void print_path(queue<int> output_queue) {
    if (output_queue.empty()) return;
    int item = output_queue.front();
    while (!output_queue.empty()) {
        item = output_queue.front();
        output_queue.pop(); 
        if (output_queue.empty()) {
            cout << "To ";
        } 
        cout << "Spot " << item << endl;
    }
}
int main() {
    int u, v;
    init();
    floyd();
    u = 1, v = 3;
    if ( dist[u][v] == INF ) cout << "No path" << endl;
    else {
        cout << "From Spot " << u << endl;
        queue<int> output_queue;
        output(u, v, output_queue);
        print_path(output_queue);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is the guide at the very beginning. Thank you all!

Comment: It helps us to see the code so that we can help you correct it.

Comment: It these are generate by iteration then you can put condition in the last iteration to print it as per your intention.

Comment: @sftrabbit code added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your output function thusly:

```
void output( int i, int j, Queue<int> &output_queue ) {
    if ( i == j ) return;
    if ( path[i][j] == 0 ) output_queue.push(j);
    else {
        output( i, path[i][j], output_queue);            // iterations
        output( path[i][j], j, output_queue);
    }
}
```

Then change your `main()`:

```
//....
else {
    Queue<int> output_queue;
    output_queue.push(u);
    output(u, v, output_queue);
    print_path(output_queue);
}
//...
```

Then add `print_path`:

```
void print_path(Queue<int> output_queue) {
    if (output_queue.empty()) return;

    auto item = output_queue.front();
    cout << "From Spot "  << item << endl;

    while (!output_queue.empty()) {
        item = output_queue.front();
        output_queue.pop();

        if (output_queue.empty()) {
            cout << "To ";"
        }
        cout << "Spot " << item << endl;
    }

}
```

A couple of things here:

- I haven't compiled or tested this. Try and figure out any errors yourself and letting me know in the comments.
- It would be really helpful for you to look at the STL. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference is a great resource for this.
- If you're not familiar with *passing by reference*, that's the strategy I used to make sure that we're adding information to the same `output_queue`. Note that I've passed by *copy* for `print_path()` because it destroys the data in the parameter. It's one of the most powerful techniques in C++.

Comment: Except `end()` is generally not incrementable.

Comment: @Angew - you're correct; what I meant to write was `for (auto x = iterable.begin(); x + 1 != iterable.end(); ++x)`.

Comment: @FabianTamp - I tired to fix the errors by adding `#include <queue>` and use `queue<int>` instead of `Queue<int>`. At last, it had one error about `auto item` in function `print_path()`: error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int. Is it alright to change `auto` to `int`? If I do so, though compile successfully, the print output is `From Spot 2` that is beyond expectation.

Comment: Ok, you need to add the equivalent of your first print statement to the queue, see `output_queue.push(u);` in the code above.

Comment: @FabianTamp - Thank you! Actually, the loop condition should be `while (!output_queue.empty())` as shown in my second time edit, or it won't jump into the loop and print the following content.

Comment: No problem. For future reference, try to make your question a little more specific from the start, and try to state 1 - what your code should be doing, 2- what it is doing, 3 - why you think it isn't working, and what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

if you have how many lines you had printed you can use this macro

```
#define gotoxy(a,b) {COORD coord; coord.X=(b); coord.Y=(a) ; SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);}
```

and go to that line and print " " for all characters you had printed.

Comment: This doesn't look like C++ to me (the language doesn't have anything like SetConsoleCursor... and the OP didn't say which platform is in use).

Answer (score 0):

It will make it easier if you do not print a newline after each line.  Then you can go back and "erase" the text on the current line by outputting a number of "\b" (backspace) characters equal to the number of characters on the line, followed by the same number of spaces (to wipe out what was there).  Then you can return to the beginning of the line by writing "\r" and write the whole line again.

Comment: Thanks John! But how can I insert all the '\r' to where they used to be?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  But anyway now that you've posted more code, I think an idea like Fabian's might be easier.